# Angular: Buttons disappear after refresh in CRUD application

Tags: angular

I'm testing a CRUD application and I'm experiencing a small problem; I have a list of products and if I click on the single product I find all its details.

In this tab, in addition to the fields, there are two buttons; one to confirm the changes that are made (Update) and another to permanently delete the product (Delete). If I try to modify any field of a product and confirm the field is modified correctly; if I try again to access and modify any field, I notice that the two buttons (ie the Update one and the Delete one) disappear.

How can I solve this problem?

product-list.component.ts

```js
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  editProfileForm!: FormGroup;
  filterTerm!:string;
  selectedProduct: any;

  constructor(private productservice: ProductService, private fb: FormBuilder, private modalService: NgbModal) {} 

  productsArray: any[] = [];
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  products: Product[] = [];
  product: Product = new Product();
  deleteMessage = false;
  productlist: any;
  isupdated = false;
  isUpdating = false;
 
  ngOnInit() {
  this.productservice.getProductList().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
    this.products = data;
    this.collectionSize=this.products.length;
    this.dtTrigger.next();
    })
    this.editProfileForm = this.fb.group({
      prodcode: [''],
      name: ['']
     });
  }

  openModal(targetModal: any, product: any) {
    this.modalService.open(targetModal, {
     centered: true,
     backdrop: 'static'
    });

    this.selectedProduct = product;
   
    this.editProfileForm!.patchValue({
     prodcode:product.prodcode, 
     name: product.name
     });
   }

  deleteProduct(prodcode: any) {
    this.productservice.deleteProduct(prodcode)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.deleteMessage = true;
          this.isupdated=false;
          this.productservice.getProductList().subscribe(data => {
            this.products = data;
          })
        },
        error => console.log(error));
  }

  productupdateform = new FormGroup({
    prodcode: new FormControl(),
    name: new FormControl()
  });

  updateProd() {
    this.product = new Product();
    this.product.prodcode = this.editProfileForm.get('prodcode')!.value;
    this.product.name = this.editProfileForm.get('name')!.value;


    this.productservice.updateProduct(this.product.prodcode!,this.product).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.isupdated = true;
        this.isUpdating = false;
        this.productservice.getProductList().subscribe(data => {
          this.products = data
          this.modalService.dismissAll();
          console.log("res:", this.editProfileForm!.getRawValue());
        })
      },
      error => console.log(error));
  }

  changeisUpdate() {
    this.isupdated = false;
    this.isUpdating = false;
  }
}
```

product-list.component.html

```js
<div class="panel-heading">

    <div class="row" [hidden]="!deleteMessage">
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
          <strong>Product delete</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th>Prod code</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
            <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" (click)="openModal(editProfileModal, product)" > {{product.prodcode}} </button></td>
          <td>{{product.name}}</td>
          <td><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/ba/Red_x.svg" width="15" height="20" (click)="deleteProduct(product.prodcode)">
          </td> 
        </tr>
      </tbody><br>
    </table>
    </div>

<ng-template #editProfileModal let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="editProfileLabel">Edit product</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="modal.dismiss()" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <form [formGroup]="editProfileForm" (ngSubmit)="updateProd()">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="prodcode" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Prod code</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="prodcode" id="prodcode">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" id="name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [hidden]="isupdated">Update</button>
        <td><button (click)="deleteProduct(selectedProduct.prodcode)" class='btn btn-danger' [hidden]="isupdated"><i class="fa fa-futboll-0">Delete</i></button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Hi, try to add some those lines after getting the product data : 
`this.products = data;
this.collectionSize=this.products.length;
this.dtTrigger.next();`

Both update and delete

Comment: are you getting any error or logs in your console ?

Comment: @AmedeAngelAulerien I tried but nothing changes

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil no there are no errors

Comment: Can you put this into a stackblitz and reproduce sharing with us the stackblitz?

Comment: Hi, 
Buttons disappeared because you use function updateProd(). 
This function sets variable 'isupdated' at true and hide the button. 
You need to reset it to false after updating data

Comment: @YellowStar22 Thanks, that was the problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happening just because you are using **isupdated** variable in buttons HTML

```
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [hidden]="isupdated">Update</button>
        <td><button (click)="deleteProduct(selectedProduct.prodcode)" class='btn btn-danger' [hidden]="isupdated"><i class="fa fa-futboll-0">Delete</i></button>
      </div>
```

and in **updateProd()** you are using
`this.isupdated = true;`
you need to set `this.isupdated = true=false;` after service response.